# Deploy one web project with multiple connection strings to multiple deployment packages

Tags: .net, deployment, msbuild, configuration-files

I have a web project, which I need to deploy to multiple (5) servers - the only difference between each server is the database connection string. I'm planning to set up a build server using TFS and MSBuild, which should build deployment packages for each of the 5 servers.

Config transformations seems the right way to go - but how do I build the same project into 5 different deployment packages, each with different connection string?

Answer (score 0):

To leverage config transformations for your environments - you need to create 5 different configurations, one for each server. Then just build each configuration before deploying to server. 
Another solution - is to call TransformXml task manually in your build script, so your single build can create 5 transformed configs in one run.